# How to check if same input is given using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've around 100 input fields with class name `questionOrder`. I have to check if user given any duplicate entry on the form input.
Currently trying something similar like this:

```
$('.questionOrder').on('input', function(){
    var inp = this.value;
    $('.questionOrder').each(function(){
        if(inp==this.value){
            console.log('match');
        }else{
            console.log('not match');
        }
    })
})
```

Problem here when inputting on a field it also checking it with itself

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove `this` element from the selector with `not()` like:

```
$('.questionOrder').not(this).each(function(){
```

**Working Code Example:**

```js
$('.questionOrder').on('input', function(){
  var inp = this.value;
  $('.questionOrder').not(this).each(function(){
    if(inp==this.value){
      console.log('match');
    }else{
      console.log('not match');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="questionOrder" value="first"/>
<input type="text" class="questionOrder" value="second"/>
<input type="text" class="questionOrder" value="third"/>
<input type="text" class="questionOrder"/>
```

Comment: Nice solution. Its good to see SO user with handsome reputation from own county.

Comment: @unreleased, thanks for the nice comment. I found SO as a great platform to enhance my knowledge and skills while helping others :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try siblings function -

```
$('.questionOrder').on('input', function(){
    var inp = this.value;
    $(this).siblings().each(function(){
        if(inp==this.value){
            console.log('match');
        }else{
            console.log('not match');
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer in pure DOM with event delegation ( without jQuery)

```js
document.body.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  switch (true) {
    case target.matches('.questionOrder'):
      var questions = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.questionOrder'))
        .forEach(function(q) {
          if (q != target) {
            if (target.value == q.value) console.log('match');
            else console.log('not match');
          }
        })
      return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="questionOrder" value="first" />
<input type="text" class="questionOrder" value="second" />
<input type="text" class="questionOrder" value="third" />
<input type="text" class="questionOrder" />
```